# Is the Landau free energy scale-invariant at the critical point?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, scale-invariance

My question is different but based on the same quote from Wikipedia as [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/350895/scale-invariance-at-phase-transitions). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance),

> In statistical mechanics, scale invariance is a feature of phase transitions. The key observation is that near a phase transition or critical point, fluctuations occur at all length scales, and thus one should look for an explicitly scale-invariant theory to describe the phenomena. Such theories are scale-invariant statistical field theories, and are formally very similar to scale-invariant quantum field theories.

**Question** I understand that at the critical point the *correlation length* $\xi$ diverges and as a consequence, the *correlation functions* $\langle\phi(\textbf{x})\phi(\textbf{y})\rangle$ behave as a power law. Power laws are scale-invariant. But for a theory itself to be scale-invariant (as Wikipedia claims) the *Landau Free energy functional* should have a scale-invariant behaviour at the critical point. But the free energy functional is a polynomial in the order parameter and polynomials are not scale-invariant.

*Then how is the claim that the relevant statistical field theory is scale-invariant justified?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a very similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360989/are-fixed-points-of-rg-evolution-really-scale-invariant/389502#389502), but in the context of quantum field theory rather than statistical field theory. The point is that it is impossible to have a nontrivial fixed point classically (i.e. without accounting for quantum/thermal fluctuations) for exactly the reason you stated: the dimensionful coefficients will define scales.

We already know that quantum/thermal fluctuations can break scale invariance, e.g. through the phenomenon of dimensional transmutation, where a quantum theory acquires a mass scale which wasn't present classically. And what's going on here is just the same process in reverse: at a nontrivial critical point the classical scale-dependence of the dimensionful coefficients is exactly canceled by quantum/thermal effects. Of course this cancellation is very special, which is why critical points are rare.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your answer. Are you saying that the statistical field theories are not scale-invariant? @knzhou

Comment: @SRS They are scale-invariant at critical points. At such points the apparent scale-dependence of a polynomial is precisely canceled by thermal effects (i.e. loop diagrams) when you perform RG.

Answer (score 1):

My background is experimental, which may not be relevant, but I wonder if the following helps... Below a boiling point some liquid at the surface will vapourize, but at the boiling point vapour, or perhaps gas, can be formed throughout the liquid. -- This is how I interpret the scale invariant nature of changes at phase transition points.

Thus, I expect that the scale-invariance is to do with the phase change being able to occur throughout the gas/liquid or solid so that if you calculate 100 molecules or 10$^6$ molecules you should get the same phase transition at the same temperature.

I realize this may all be just blindingly obvious and/or irrelevant, but hope it may be helpful and perhaps part of the answer you are looking for.