# Is there a natural scale associated with polynomials?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, scale-invariance, scales

This question is related to a previous question asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394732/is-the-landau-free-energy-scale-invariant-at-the-critical-point).

Power laws are scale invariant. They don't have a built-in or characteristic scale associated with them. Exponentials such as $e^{-x/\xi}$ are not scale-invariant. They have a characteristic scale $\xi$. What is the matter with polynomials such as $f(x)=ax^2+bx^3$ (where $x,a,b$ are all dimensional parameters with appropriate dimension)? Like exponentials, they too are not scale-invariant. *But is there a natural scale associated with it? If yes, how does one find that hidden scale?*

Comment: I guess the natural scale may be hidden in constants like $h$, for example. - as implied by answer just now by Steven and the other answer

Comment: @tom The question is how to identify the hidden scale.

Comment: This seems to be a question about mathematics, not physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil It's important to understand if one wishes to understand scale invariance in physics. Moreover, mathematicians (as far as I know) is not used to the language of "length scales", "characteristic scales" etc. And It's, of course, related to physics. See my question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394732/is-the-landau-free-energy-scale-invariant-at-the-critical-point

Comment: So I looked at your Landau free energy scale question and I think I understand more about what you are asking. I will comment there.

Comment: Differential equations are also important in physics, but that does not mean questions about differential equations should be posted here instead of Mathematics SE. This question lacks physics context. Perhaps it should have been asked as part of your other question, which is the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your polynomial as $f(x) = ax^2 [1+ x/(a/b)]$. You see that $a/b$ is the scale at which the $x^3$ term takes over.

Take a look at the log-log plot of $f(x)$ for different values of $l=a/b$. The black lines are there to guide the eye. The dashed line corresponds $x^2$ and the dotted one to $x^3$.

[image]

Take a look at the red curve. It scales as $x^2$ for small arguments and as $x^3$ when $x$ is large. The cross-over scale is clearly visible in the middle.

Comment: Do you mean $a/b$ is the natural scale? I don't understand why. Does your argument hold good for polynomials of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx^3+cx^4$ or of higher orders? You think there will be a single characteristic scale? @StevenMathey

Comment: Yes. For $x\ll l$, the $x^3$ term can be neglected and $f \sim x^2$. For $x \gg l$, the $x^3$ term completely overwhelms the other and $f \sim x^3$. For higher order polynomials, you have more scales in the problem, $f(x) = a x^2 [1 + x/l_1 + (x/l_2)^2]$, with $l_1 = a/b$ and $l_2 = \sqrt{a/c}$.

Comment: Can you slightly edit your answer? I've accidentally downvoted it, and cannot undo the downvote unless you edit it a bit. @StevemMathey

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem with
$$
f(x)= x^2+x^3
$$
in that, if $x$ is not dimensionless, then various powers in your polynomials will have different dimensions and so cannot strictly be added.  If of course you make $x$ dimensionless by dividing $x$ by some characteristic scale $a$, then you're back to the same argument as the exponential examples.

[See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/364776/36194).]

Comment: I've been careless in asking the question. Now I have modified the question. Is there a way I can identify some natural scale with $f(x)$? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: This looks like a comment rather than an answer.